# Passing multiple chunks of data using pipe in C

Tags: c, operating-system, posix

I need to send 3 char buffers to child process and I want to treat them as 3 separate chunks of data. I thought of using `read()` and `write()` system calls but after reading man I can't see a way to separate the data - if I understand it correctly, if I write 3 buffers one by one in parent process, then one call of `read()` will read all the data. Of course I could put some separators like `'\0'` in input buffers and separate the data in child, but I'm looking for some more elegant way to do this. So, is there some kind of system call that enables to pass data sequentially?

Comment: Be aware that a `write()` of more than `PIPE_BUF` bytes may not be atomic and may therefore require multiple partial `read()` calls and/or may be interleaved with data from other `write()` calls.  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use what `stdio.h` already gives you: `fdopen()` the respective ends of the pipes and use `fgets()`/`fputs()` with the `FILE` pointers. This assumes your data doesn't contain newlines.

Some alternatives could be to use fixed sizes with `read()`/`write()` or to use some other delimiter and parse the received data with `strtok()`. You could also send the size first so the child knows how many bytes to read in the next `read()` call. There are really lots of options.

Answer (score 1):

If you have it, you can use [`O_DIRECT` to get a "packet-oriented" pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), but there are limitations of course.

In general for a text-based streamed protocol having separators is cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: A packet-oriented pipe using `O_DIRECT` seems to be a Linux-specific extension.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices

1. Put delimiters in the data (as you mentioned in the question).
2. Provide feedback from the child. In other words, after writing a chunk of data to the pipe, the parent waits for a response from the child, e.g. on a second pipe, or using a semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

You could precede each chunk of data with a header, including a length field if chunks can be variable length.  The reader can read the header and then the chunk contents.